# c# DataTime: Assume EST convert to GTM

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a server running in New York that saves a DateTime into the database in local time.

I then have a client application running in GMT timezone that needs to save down a DateTime in the same local New York time
Can I do using:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"))
```

Or I need to consider daylight savings?

Now in my UI I need to display 2 columns. 1) the DateTime from the database and the DateTime in the database converted to GMT

How can I do this?

Comment: If it's really in EST, you can just add 5 hours. But I suspect it's more likely to be in Eastern Time - sometimes EST, sometimes EDT. At that point, you need to know exactly *which* Eastern Time, as different versions of ET transition at different times, or have done historically...

Comment: Thanks Jon. Wouldn't I need to take daylight savings into account rather than just adding 5 hours?

Comment: That was the point of my comment - you wouldn't in order to convert from Eastern *Standard* Time, no... but if you're converting from "sometimes Eastern Standard Time, sometimes Eastern Daylight Time" then you do. There's a huge difference between Eastern Time and Eastern Standard Time.

Comment: Hi Jon. I updated my question as I wasn't asking it correctly. I hope it's more clear now

Comment: Yes, definitely, although the title is still incorrect.

Comment: The code you have will in fact take DST into account. At least it did when I tested it here some time back. It's easy enough to test. Use your code to convert a date/time that falls within EST, and one that falls within EDT. You should see different time deltas.

Comment: Right, had started to write an answer here, but then had to take a call. The only thing I'd add here is that by recording local time, you're losing information: you won't be able to tell the difference between the first occurrence of 1:30am on Sunday November 5th and the second occurrence. You should work out what you want to do in this situation.

Comment: You should **never** store local time in a database. This is a **very bad** idea. As explained in a comment, it might cause some ambiguity. Also, if the server is ever moved, the code would probably use another time zone so all time would because incorrect. This was a poor design decision and the best thing to do would be to modify the data and fix the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TimeZoneInfo class should give you what you need.

```
var date = (DateTime)reader[0]; // Retrieve data from database however you normally get it

var est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date, est);

var localTime = utcTime.ToLocalTime();
```

Edit: You modified your question to indicate you have looked at TimeZoneInfo, so this doesn't add much anymore. However to resolve the ambiguous time issue mentioned by Jon, take a look at the `IsAmbiguousTime()` and `GetAmbiguousTimeOffsets()` methods to be able to detect values that can't be definitively converted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample to show that it should work as expected. That is, it will do the DST conversion.

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2016, 06, 01, 08, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);  // Daylight saving time
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2016, 12, 01, 08, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);  // Standard time

var dt1Converted = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt1,
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"));
var dt2Converted = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt2,
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"));

var diff1 = (dt1Converted - dt1).TotalHours;
var diff2 = (dt2Converted - dt2).TotalHours;

Console.WriteLine($"dt1: {dt1}, converted: {dt1Converted}, diff: {diff1}");
Console.WriteLine($"dt2: {dt2}, converted: {dt2Converted}, diff: {diff2}");
```

Output:

```
dt1: 2016-06-01 08:00:00, converted: 2016-06-01 12:00:00, diff: 4
dt2: 2016-12-01 08:00:00, converted: 2016-12-01 13:00:00, diff: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you can change this to use `DateTimeOffset` ? It was designed to resolve all of these problems